# Access problem on JSON file in JavaScript / HTML, can not reach key/values

Tags: javascript, html, json

For an HTML site, I use a JSON file from a website to fill a table.

My script looks like this:

```
<script>
      fetch ("[LINK]")
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data){
          addData(data);
        })
      function addData(data){
       var table = document.getElementById("apiinventory");


       let text = "";
       for (x in data) {
          var row = table.insertRow(0);
          var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
          var cellPrice = row.insertCell(1);
          var cellAmount = row.insertCell(2);

          cellName.innerHTML = x;          
          cellPrice.innerHTML = data[x].price;
          cellAmount.innerHTML = data[x].casesLeft;
          text += x;
       }
      }
    </script>
```

And my JSON file looks like this: (only a snippet)

```
{"CS20 Case": {"0": {"date": "Oct 18 2019 01: +0", "price": 5.467, "casesLeft": "55948"}, "1": {"date": "Oct 19 2019 01: +0", "price": 2.992, "casesLeft": "267246"}
```

I managed to display the names of the objects (CS20, Operation Phoenix Weapon Case) in my first cell, but I don't manage to get the values of date, price and casesLeft into the other cells.

Everything I try to access the key/values, I always run into "undefined" outputs instead of the actual values.

Is there anything wrong in my previous parts of the code or am I doing something wrong with my call for the value of the JSON?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that is your JSON it should be a string - and it is missing some `}}` at the end

Comment: the data in your case contains one object on the first level that holds your data and stored in key "CS20 Case", you need to get the entries of this object, not the root data object

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks first of all, the brackets at the end are of course there, it's just the first couple of key/values i pasted in. I guess I do that by using JSON.stringify, but can you help me in placing this correctly in my code? I know the command but I don't know where to place it exactly, my own code is a bit of a mess to me.

Comment: @Zac yes i understand that (i think) but i don't know how to access it by code. Can you maybe write that line in the correct format so I can understand it from there?

Comment: You need to do something like `addData(data["CS20 Case"])`.

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
fetch ("[LINK]")
  .then( resp => resp.json() )
  .then( data => {
    addData(data['CS20 Case'])
  })
  
function addData(info){
  const table = document.getElementById('apiinventory')

  for (let key in info) {
    let row = table.insertRow()
    row.insertCell().textContent = info[key].date
    row.insertCell().textContent = info[key].price
    row.insertCell().textContent = info[key].casesLeft
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data[x]` from your code has:

```
{"0": {"date": "Oct 18 2019 01: +0", "price": 5.467, "casesLeft": "55948"}, "1": {"date": "Oct 19 2019 01: +0", "price": 2.992, "casesLeft": "267246"}}
```

Hence, there is no `price` in `data[x]`, rather an object itself. So, if you instead took the key 0 from the value of data[x], such as `data[x][0].price`, it will give you the price of the first item of the object.

You should have one more loop inside the first loop where loop through the objects inside `data[x]` and print each item.